# Multiple insert with variable number of parameters SQL

Tags: oracle, insert, unpivot

I have a table t_test on Oracle 11g with two fields:

```
CITY  NAME
----- --------------
MIAMI JOHN
MIAMI ERNEST
MIAMI ERICK
TAMPA DAN
```

I want to insert multiple rows on that query using just one insert command, and passing the values for `NAME` as a parameter in the query. It would be something like this:

```
INSERT INTO T_TEST (CITY, NAME)
SELECT :1,(:2,:3,:4,:5) from dual
```

where the parameter 1 would be Miami, and the parameters 2, 3, 4 and 5 would be the diferent names.

I've been seeing some examples, and I thinking the best option would be an unpivot, so I would have a subquery that would return the names as rows in a table, but I don't know how to use the unpivot to do that.

Comment: Just a clarification. The number of possible names is variable, and I'm able to expand a parameter as many times as I want (so I can convert :2 to :2, :3, :4, etc) but I can not multiply other parts of the query, so solutions as multiple DECODEs are not an option.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing fancy here, just a catesian join (i.e. join with no condition)

```
INSERT INTO T_TEST (CITY,NAME)
SELECT C.city
    ,  N.name
FROM   ( SELECT :1 AS city FROM DUAL ) C
    ,  ( SELECT DECODE( LEVEL, 1, :1
                             , 2, :2
                             , 3, :3
                             , 4, :4
                             , 5, :5 ) AS name
         FROM DUAL
         CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 5 ) N
```

Comment: Sorry, I just add a note adding to the problem, so you solution, while util, does not solve my problem. At some place in the query I should have a parameter :X, which I will expand to :x,:(x+1),:(x+2), etc in order to accommodate all the possible values.

Comment: I was not aware you could do that. I thought you always had to have a fixed number of bind variables. To do what you want I would have to write some code which dynamically built the SQL (namely the `DECODE` statement) and also added a list of variables as it went. But my knowledge is old so there could well be new ways to do this. Be keen to see what comes up. Our of interest, what language/platform are you embedding your SQL into?